# suddenly started receiving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

My android app is more than a year on Play now and everything was OK.
About 2 weeks ago users started complaining on crashes. Than was strange cause I haven't changed anything for some time now.
Yesterday, after finally taking a look on crash logs, I've noticed huge number NoClassDefFoundError being thrown, which led to crashes in the app.

3 strange things:
1) GameplayFragment$TimerUpdater is of course present.
1) The app has not been updated for months.
2) Apparently only GINGERBREAD versions crash

Has anybody experienced this?

Thanks

```
[main] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ivygames.morskoiboi.ui.GameplayFragment$TimerUpdater at 
com.ivygames.morskoiboi.ui.GameplayFragment.startTimer(GameplayFragment.java:336) at 
com.ivygames.morskoiboi.ui.GameplayFragment.access$10(GameplayFragment.java:333) at 
com.ivygames.morskoiboi.ui.GameplayFragment$UiProxy$1.run(GameplayFragment.java:495) at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ivygames.morskoiboi.ui.GameplayFragment$TimerUpdater in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ivygames.morskoiboi-1.apk] at 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) ... 12 more (BOARD=codina; BOOTLOADER=unknown; BRAND=samsung; CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a; DEVICE=GT-I8160; DISPLAY=GINGERBREAD.XXLL2; HARDWARE=samsung; HOST=DELL205; ID=GINGERBREAD; MANUFACTURER=samsung; MODEL=GT-I8160; PRODUCT=GT-I8160; USER=dpi; SDK=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see minimum sdk version required you can set it to lower android version i.e 7 or 8

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="9", but why should I lower it? The app is supposed to run on SDK 9+

Also I still don't understand what has happened - the app worked for months.